# Integer out of range. when I use to_numeric() on string in Python

Tags: python

I have a column containing numbers in a string format. I want to convert them to numbers so I use `to_numeric()` on the said column and then get Integer out of range error.

Here is a number straight from my dataset:

```
x: 3934057714693296797966
```

```
df_test['Number_converted']=pd.to_numeric(df_test['Number_string'])
```

The largest number I have in my population is 28 digits. Any ideas how I can deal with this error?

Looks like the thing I am using cannot handle such big numbers

Comment: You can check this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/converting-data-to-a-numeric-type-in-pandas-db9415caab0b)

Comment: use pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) operation, this will be useful on many occasions.

Comment: What version of python are you using ?

Comment: @Gaston, I am using Python 3.0

Comment: @Nikolaus, great tutorial. Thanks a lot. Adding astype('Int64') to the to_numeric() actually solved my issue.

`df_test['Number_converted']=pd.to_numeric(df_test['Number_string']).astype('Int64')`